# Why doesn't ASSETS folder get created when installing with ADB instead of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, vulkan, android-assets

I'm running the Android version of "Vulkan Best Practices" from GitHub here.

https://github.com/ARM-software/vulkan_best_practice_for_mobile_developers

It's working fine when deployed from Android Studio, but if I install the exact same APK with ADB it doesn't create the ASSETS folder and therefore crashes when trying to load resources from there.

I'm running on a Samsung S10 with Android 11, and using the latest BB version of Android Studio, as well as the latest SDK 31.

I don't know if it's related, but on my S21 running Android 12, it won't even run when loaded with Android Studio. The ASSETS folder is never created on Android 12, no matter how the APK is installed.

When I mount the APK with Winzip or the Apk Analyzer, I don't see an ASSETS folder there at all, so I'm not sure where it comes from even in the one case where it works.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on why running from Android Studio vs. ADB would behave this way?  Or perhaps what's different with Android 12 in this regard?

Comment: You're confused. There is no assets folder.  When you turn it into an APK, it becomes files inside of the apk (which is a zip) and is accessed from there-  it never becomes a folder on disk on the device.  It's been this way since the initial release of Android with 1.6.  So something else is going on.  And having been programming Android since Cupcake, I've never seen an app not install via adb.  In fact all Android Studio does is use adb behind the scenes.

Comment: Actually wait 1 thought-  if rather than the Android concept of assets you mean that it creates a folder called access on the first time you run it-  in Android 11 all the rules for filesystem access changed.  The app may not have updated for them.

Comment: @Bungles FYI: the github repo you are referencing has been moved to https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples and has a Android build doc: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/docs/build.md#android This part on 3D models may be relevant: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/docs/build.md#3d-models

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, everyone. Yes I'm talking about the Assets folder that's supposed to get automatically created on the device. What would cause it to not be created? It's within the sandbox file system, so there shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Also, I tried the newer repository and that one won't even build with the latest version of Android Studio. I'll see if I can get it to build, but it'd be nice if they kept up to date with Android build tools.